# pyversion in MATLAB shows that anaconda is using Python2.7 lib but anaconda version is '3.5'

Tags: python, matlab, anaconda

In Mac Os, when I input the command `pyversion` in MATLAB, I obtain the following result

```
>> pyversion
 version: '3.5'
    executable: '//anaconda/bin/python'
       library: '//anaconda/lib/libpython2.7.dylib'
          home: '//anaconda'
      isloaded: 0
```

Why is the dynamic library different from the version? How can I change it?

Comment: Look here: https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/faq#does-anaconda-include-python-2-or-python-3

Did you install anaconda2 or anaconda3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having checked that in the anaconda lib folder it was present the `libpython3.5` library, I simply typed in MATLAB `pyversion 3.5`, and this fixed the problem.